# Поиск строки в которой нет подстроки title=""

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно при помощи регулярных выражений найти те ссылки в которых отсутствует подстрока title="", то есть пропустить вот эти ссылки:

```
<a href="/images/gallery-images/white-on-white/2.jpg" itemprop="contentURL" title="Текст"/>
```

и найти вот такие:

```
<a href="/images/gallery-images/white-on-white/2.jpg" itemprop="contentURL" title=""/> 
<a href="/images/gallery-images/white-on-white/2.jpg" itemprop="contentURL"/>
```

Comment: почему именно регуляркой, разбор html регулярками очень неблагодарное занятие. а то встретится вам `<a href="site.com/a.php?title='abc' itemprop=1>"`. Так что совершенно правильная регулярка должна будет учесть все нюансы формирования тегов и разного рода экранирования, разумеется реально, но если она окажется в размере пару килобайт и на ее создание уйдет месяц сильно удивляться не надо. А все простое и быстросозданное может ломаться в самых непредсказуемых местах

Comment: полностью с вами согласен, но здесь другая ситуация, все ссылки имеют +/- одинаковый вид без GET параметров. Да и тут просто принципиальный вопрос, решить именно регулярным выражением

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например так:

```
<a (?![^>]*title=".+?").*?\/>
```

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/yk7oIo/1)

Ищем просмотром вперед такие `<a` внутри которых (до  `>`) не содержится подходящего по условию title.